# What's a classroom demonstration that an object with balanced forces can move at a constant velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, education

It is quite easy to demonstrate that an object at rest that has balanced forces doesn't move. All the Internet examples of things that have balanced forced moving are large scale objects - cars and airplanes. I thought of something like a deployable parachute on a light object but it sounds complicated to set up. What is a good demonstation of balanced forces producing a roughly constant velocity?

Answer (score 1):

This would usually be done in the high school physics classroom with an air track and two equal weights that pull the glider at the same time in two opposite directions. You can, of course, dispense with the track completely and just hang two equal weights on a pulley. That works just fine, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a balloon, possibly with a light weight hanging from it to show air resistance balancing gravity. This would be easier to set up than a parachute, and would reach equilibrium pretty quickly. You'd need to control stray air currents of course.

Comment: Sounds easier for me with no equipment- I am just teaching a child alone but how does it ensure it moves.

Comment: An air table (game arcade style) can be good too.

Answer (score -2):

Ok here is a very simple reason that why the object moves with a constant velocity(You may be knowing it).
It is because of viscous force which comes into play.Let's try to understand it using a sphere for which the viscous force is given by
$$
F_v=6\pi\eta rv
$$
for diffrent bodies it could be diffrent
And by solving for the case where the object is moving at constant velocity or what we technically call it "Terminal Velocity":
$$
v_t=\frac{2}{9\eta}(\sigma-\rho)r^2g
$$
**Now you will be wondering why I gave you this stuff that you already know?** Well what you can perform is actually related and is much simpler than the parachute problem.What you need is a transparent flask and a ball having density higher than water. What you will observe is that the motion is approximately uniform.Why "Approximately"? It's because When you solve for the time it take to reach terminal velocity the answer is $\infty$(Its a fun exersize to do, The answer is exponential)But it reachers quite close to terminal velocity just in few sec.It's not perfect but nothing is perfect but it can give a good idea to students.
For other thing you can show them animation of forced Oscillation (Just don't tell them what it is,cuz it's a bit scary) in which the external force is same as the force due to spring(because of which the block will move with same velocity). That was my personal suggestion. I hope it helps.
edit:You also need to take Buoyant force into account when in water.

Comment: How is that a demonstration that the forces are balanced, though? I am not aware of a simple way to measure the fluid-dynamical forces on a moving ball. You are basically using that the forces are balanced to arrive at the very equation you are using to show that the forces are balanced.... unless you have access to a well calibrated wind or water tunnel on a high school bench?